# Setting up a server-side script to continuously record streamed JSON data from an API in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, api

I am trying to set up a server-side connection to an API that continuously parses and records the API's JSON response in a MySQL database throughout the day. My site is set-up as a Wordpress site, and so any Wordpress specific solutions work too.

I know how to keep a connection open and print the responses as they come in using Python, for example. Something like this works:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           "Authorization": "Bearer api_key_here"}
baseurl = 'http://stream.url/here'
payload = { 'key_id' : 'key'}

r = requests.get(baseurl, params=payload, headers=headers, stream=True)
print(r.headers)
print('\n')

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line:
        print(json.loads(line.decode("utf-8")))
```

The output from the above script trickles out line by line as it comes in from the API server.
For example, suppose I get a response like this every second:

```
{'type': 'TYPE', 'time': '2019-11-18T21:07:12.422789431Z', 'key1': [{'dat1': '1.10739', 'dat2': 10000000}], 'key2': [{'dat1': '1.10752', 'dat2': 10000000}]}
```

What I am trying to do now is to set up a server side script (preferably in PHP but I can work with other solutions too) that basically does this, except instead of printing the response, it records it into a database table, in real-time, throughout the day.

I don't have much experience setting up a server side script like this, so not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

PHP really doesn't "listen" well. You really have two options:

1. Cronjob that calls a php script that checks the output and runs every few seconds.
2. Have your python script POST to somewhere instead of / in addition to print.